# $\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{0}\iff\frac{u}{dx}=\frac{1}{dt}=\frac{0}{du}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, divisibility

Days ago I saw this:

... (1) we have $$\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{0}$$

i.e.

$$\frac{u}{dx}=\frac{1}{dt}=\frac{0}{du}$$

Why are both equalities equivalent ?

I can see that $\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dt}{1}\iff\frac{u}{dx}=\frac{1}{dt}$ but then you have to swap again  with the other expression $\frac{du}{0}$
 to have $\frac{0}{du}$ but if you do this then you will modify this $\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dt}{1}\iff\frac{u}{dx}=\frac{1}{dt}$ again, i.e. you wouldn't end up having $\frac{u}{dx}=\frac{1}{dt}=\frac{0}{du}$.

---

**Edit**

Consider the equation $u_t+uu_x=0$, then we have (1)

Comment: oh jeez, you'll definitely want to define what you mean by the first string of equalities. As written, it doesn't  mean much

Comment: @qbert I thought the DE was not necessary to write, but I did it now, and the meaning of the string of equalities is a 'way' to get to the solution of PDE

Comment: What is $du/0$?

Comment: @FedePoncio I don't know. I'd like to know too, but don't get distracted of the main question :)

Comment: Is it just an algebraic trick? what is it?

Comment: Yes I have seen this written for the method of characteristics as well. I do believe it's a sort of "trick" to represent the system compactly. But to have any hope of figuring out why those two are equivalent, it seems requisite to know what the first one even means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{0}=ds$$

I wouldn't say that is is a trick. May be a more convenient word is a short-cut, i.e. a synoptic way to write :
$$\frac{dx}{u}=ds$$
$$\frac{dt}{1}=ds$$
$$\frac{du}{0}=ds$$

On a formal manner:

$$\frac{1}{ds}=\frac{u}{dx}$$
$$\frac{1}{ds}=\frac{1}{dt}$$
$$\frac{1}{ds}=\frac{0}{du}$$

and so :

$$\frac{1}{ds}=\frac{u}{dx}=\frac{1}{dt}=\frac{0}{du}$$

All this cannot be understood independently from the theory of the method of characteristics, which can be found in textbooks and which leads to more extended relationships.

The above symbolic is useful to simplify the writing in some cases. For example, see section 2.2 in 
http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~kersale/Teach/M3414/Notes/m3414_2.pdf

EXAMPLE : 
$$u_t+uu_x=0$$
$\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{0}$

A first family of characteristic curves comes from $\quad \frac{du}{0}=$finite$\quad\implies du=0$.
$$u=c_1$$
A second family of characteristic curves comes from $\quad \frac{dx}{c_1}=\frac{dt}{1}$
$$c_1t-x=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE, expressed on the form of implicit equation, is :
$$\Phi\left(u\:,\: u\,t-x \right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is an arbitrary function of two variables, to be determined according to the boundary and/or initial condition.

Equivalently :
$$u=F(u\,t-x) \tag 1$$
where $F$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to the boundary and/or initial condition.

Without specified condition one cannot go further.

With some well posed condition, the function $F$ can be determined. Then in some cases (not always) Eq.$(1)$ can be solved for $u$ and the solution $u(x,t)$ is explicitly obtained. In other cases, the solution remains on the form of an implicit equation.

$$ $$

Comment: what an answer, thank you.

Comment: I just have one question what do you mean with $\frac{du}{0}=finite\implies du=0$?

Comment: $\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{0}$ The two first terms have finite values (not infinite). Thus the third term is not infinite, which implies $du=0$. Another manner is to consider  $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{0}$ giving $0*dt=1*du$ hence $du=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\cfrac{dx}{u}=\cfrac{dt}{1}=\cfrac{du}{0}$

The above equation is represented like this for making things simple.

We just take two equations at a time, cross multiply it and then deal with those equations in general.

As the equivalent equation gives the same equation(s), thats why they both are equivalent in this case.

$\cfrac{dx}{u}=\cfrac{dt}{1}$
$ dx *1 = dt * u$

$\cfrac{dt}{1}=\cfrac{du}{0}$
$ 0*dt = 1 * du$

$\cfrac{dx}{u} = \cfrac{du}{0}$
$0*dx = u*du$